# Background colour changer

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create multiple buttons ROYGBV. I want to use JS to attribute a function whereby when I click a button, the background colour changes. The one I have just seems too long.
Can some help with this?

```
function myFunctionRed(){document.body.style.backgroundColor="red";}
function myFunctionOrange(){document.body.style.backgroundColor="orange";}
function myFunctionYellow(){document.body.style.backgroundColor="yellow";}
function myFunctionGreen(){document.body.style.backgroundColor="limegreen";}
function myFunctionBlue(){document.body.style.backgroundColor="blue";}
function myFunctionIndigo(){document.body.style.backgroundColor="#4B0082";}
function myFunctionViolet(){document.body.style.backgroundColor="violet";}
```

Comment: why make a function for each color? Why not pass the color as a parameter instead. `function colorChange(color) {document.body.style.backgroundColor=color}`?

Comment: The obvious thing to do is have a single function that takes the color as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks @MissSkooterI am tend to overthink JS as I am still learning. I am working on that

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify it in order to use only one function that accepts a color argument like:

```js
function setBodyBgColor(color) { document.body.style.backgroundColor = color; }
```

and use like:

```js
setBodyBgColor("red");
// or
setBodyBgColor("hsla(180, 80%, 80%, 0.8)")
```

You could make it even more flexible, and also pass the element you want to style:

```js
function setBgColor (elem, color) { elem.style.background = color; }

setBgColor(document.body, "blue");
```

But, it makes not great use to have a function that all it does is change a background color. Instead, create a function that can apply any style, and more CSS properties at once:

```js
const css = (el, styles) => typeof styles === "object" ? Object.assign(el.style, styles) : el.style.cssText = styles;


// Use like:

css(document.body, {
  color: "red",
  background: "blue",
  fontSize: "2rem"
});

// Or like:

css(document.querySelector("#someElement"), `
  color: red;
  background: blue;
  font-size: 2rem;
`)
```

Comment: Thanks so much. These seem like interesting concept. I'll try them. I'm still learning to use JS. If you have any tips on how to progress and become fluent in this language, I will appreciate it.

Comment: @Jonny you're welcome. I'm happy to inform you that to learn a language - it takes time and practice :) Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

```
function myColor(color,element) {
  let el = document.querySelector(element);
  element.style.backgroundColor = color;
} 

//use in html 
<button onclick="myColor('red','body')">R</button>
<button onclick="myColor('green','body')">G</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion

It is longer than just passing a colour to a function but it shows you some interesting methods to study

```js
const colors = {
  "red": "red",
  "orange": "orange",
  "yellow": "yellow",
  "limegreen": "limegreen",
  "blue": "blue",
  "hex": "#4B0082",
  "violet": "violet"
};
const colorKeys = Object.keys(colors);
const colorEntries = Object.entries(colors);

const createStyleSheet = () => {
  let head = document.querySelector('head'),
    style = document.createElement('style'),
    css = colorEntries
    .map(([name, color]) => `.${name}-bc { background-color: ${color}}`)
    .join('\n');
  css += '.colorButton { text-transform: capitalize;}'; // Uppercase first letter of button text
  style.type = 'text/css';
  style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css))
  head.appendChild(style);
};
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  createStyleSheet();
  const bodyCL = document.body.classList;
  const colorDiv = document.getElementById('colorDiv');

  colorDiv.innerHTML = colorEntries
    .map(([name, color]) => `<button class="colorButton ${name}-bc" value="${name}">${color}</button>`).join('');
  colorDiv.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const tgt = e.target;
    if (!tgt.matches('.colorButton')) return; // not a button
    colorKeys.forEach(color => bodyCL.remove(`${color}-bc`)); // remove previous
    bodyCL.add(`${tgt.value}-bc`);
  });
})
```

```html
<div id="colorDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the function like below :

```js
function setBackgroundColor(color){
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```